# Filtering Text by Prefix in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, text

Hello fellow developers on Stack Overflow,

I hope this message finds you well. I would like to share a code snippet with you that utilizes the tkinter library in Python 3 to create a window with a text widget, a "Run" button, and a "Filter by Prefix" menu option under the "Edit" menu. The intention of this code is to allow users to enter text in the text widget and specify a prefix using the "Filter by Prefix" option, and then click the "Run" button to filter out words in the text that do not start with the specified prefix.

However, the code is not currently functioning as expected. Despite following the proper syntax and structure of tkinter, the filter by prefix operation is not providing the desired output. Upon clicking the "Run" button or selecting the "Filter by Prefix" option from the menu, the text in the text widget is getting deleted completely, rather than being filtered as per the specified prefix.

I have reviewed the code thoroughly, and upon further investigation, it appears that the issue may be related to the filter_by_prefix() function, which is triggered by the "Run" button and the "Filter by Prefix" menu option. This function is designed to extract the entered prefix from an entry widget, retrieve the text from the text widget, perform the filtering operation, and update the text widget with the filtered text. However, it seems that the function is not executing as intended, resulting in the deletion of all the text in the text widget instead of filtering it. Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

# Function to run the filter by prefix operation
def filter_by_prefix():
    prefix = prefix_entry.get()
    text = text_widget.get(1.0, tk.END)
    lines = text.split('\n')
    filtered_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        words = line.split()
        filtered_words = [word for word in words if word.startswith(prefix)]
        filtered_line = ' '.join(filtered_words)
        filtered_lines.append(filtered_line)
    filtered_text = '\n'.join(filtered_lines)
    text_widget.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    text_widget.insert(tk.END, filtered_text)

# Function to handle "Filter by Prefix" menu option
def on_filter_by_prefix():
    prefix_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    prefix_window.title("Filter by Prefix")
    prefix_window.geometry("300x100")
    prefix_label = tk.Label(prefix_window, text="Enter prefix:")
    prefix_label.pack()
    global prefix_entry
    prefix_entry = tk.Entry(prefix_window)
    prefix_entry.pack()
    prefix_button = tk.Button(prefix_window, text="Filter", command=filter_by_prefix)
    prefix_button.pack()

# Create main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Text Filter")
root.geometry("400x400")

# Create text widget
text_widget = tk.Text(root)
text_widget.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

# Create "Run" button
run_button = tk.Button(root, text="Run", command=filter_by_prefix)
run_button.pack()

# Create menu bar
menu_bar = tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu_bar)

# Create "Edit" menu
edit_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=False)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit_menu)

# Add "Filter by Prefix" menu option
edit_menu.add_command(label="Filter by Prefix", command=on_filter_by_prefix)

# Run tkinter event loop
root.mainloop()
```

I would appreciate your assistance in identifying and resolving the issue in this code. Your expertise and insights would be invaluable in helping me determine the root cause of the problem and finding a solution to make the code function as expected, i.e., filtering the text based on the specified prefix without deleting the entire text.

Thank you in advance for your assistance, and I look forward to your valuable contributions.

Comment: I wonder why I have already a downvote while I did my best to explain the issue and before that, my best to do this code by making researches about it. I would be glad anyone thinking I deserve that warns me before so I know the issue as well

Comment: What are your inputs? I could not reproduce the error.

Comment: @Shorn sorry about that, my inputs were some of those: FX_ ; GUI_ ; TMP_ ; CFG_ ; SYS_ ; in short all was ending with an underscore.

Comment: still unable to reproduce the error. Also, for future reference, please edit your inputs into the question, and in cases like this provide the inputs that cause the error. The example inputs you provided are still ambiguous as to whether they are the filter inputs or the text inputs. I've assumed that they are meant to be the text input since your code does not simultaneously handle multiple filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized that the error was due to a simple oversight on my part.

The text widget I was using didn't have word wrap and scrollbars enabled, resulting in long lines of text that were hidden beyond the visible window area. I've now resolved the issue by adding the necessary functions to the text widget.